# What do I have to consider when using std::sort with a parallel execution policy?

Tags: c++, c++17

With C++17, we got Execution Policies.
I am interested in the [parallel policies](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t)

What do I have to consider when I use `std::sort` with a parallel policy?
Unlike `std::transform` or `std::for_each`, `std::sort` accesses two elements at the same time. Do I have to take data races into consideration here?

Comment: Neither sort nor any valid ordering function should modify the values of the container being sorted. So there's really no need for `std::sort` to do any synchronization itself. With that said, if you have other threads which could modify the container or its stored values while `std::sort` is running then then that's another matter, but it's not something `std::sort` can protect against. It's your responsibility to protect against such cases.

Comment: @SomeProgrammerDude it may be a language barrier, but it feels really weird to see an assertion that "*sort [...] should [not] modify the values of the container being sorted*". Well, it obviously modifies them because it swaps them, which changes the very objects that are being swapped. Though I believe I am getting what you intended to communicate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything *extra* to consider when calling `std::sort` with an execution policy. It is already UB for your compare to mutate the elements it is comparing.

The implementation is required to ensure there are no data races within any of the functions defined in `std`.